# Kafka connect maximum active tasks in the consumer_group

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I have a connector that consume 2 topics

1 topic with 6 partitions and the second topic with 2 partitions ( 8 partitions in total to consume)

When I set tasks.max under 6 the partitions to consume are well balanced between the tasks (by looking the consumer_group)

[image]
[image]

But If I set tasks.max to upper than 6 , by example 8 , then I have two task without topics attribution in the consumer_group ( all the 8 tasks are in RUNNING state ), so there is 2 idle tasks

[image]
[image]

the topic **offset.storage.topic** only have 6 partitions

It is impossible for a connector to have more active (not only running) task than the number of partitions of the topic offset.storage.topic ?

So is the value offset.storage.partitions related to max active connector task ?

[the confluent doc say](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/allconfigs.html#distributed-worker-configuration) ->

> offset.storage.topic :
>
> topic with a large number of partitions (e.g., 25 or 50, just like
> Kafka’s built-in __consumer_offsets topic) to support large Kafka
> Connect clusters.

Comment: completely off topic but what UI is that?

Comment: it's AKHQ , but I would now recommend provectus-kafka-ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In kafka-connect 2.7

**The maximum number of active task for a sink connector is equal to the topic with the biggest number of partitions to consume**

because it's using the RangeAssignor partition assignment strategy

*(it's not related to the number of partitions of the topic offset.storage.partitions)*

An active task is a task with partition attributed in the consumer-group of the sink connector

example :

With 2 topics where each have 10 partitions

The maximum number of active task is 10 ( if I set task.max at 12 , 2 task in the consumer-group do not have partitions to consume).

If I add a third topic with 15 partitions to the connector conf then the 12 task receive partitions to consume , and then if I set now task.max at 17 only 15 task are active in the consumer-group.

---

Only way I found to force an equal distribution of the partitions between all the members of the consumer-group is to set

```json
"consumer.override.partition.assignment.strategy": "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor"
```

Answer (score 1):

`tasks.max` configuration comes from the framework and specifies the maximum number of tasks to be created for the connector. But, fewer tasks may be created. - https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/configuring.html

In this case, the framework decides that it only needs # tasks to handle the load, so each task handles related topic-partitions. Which, is fine from the framework perspective since each partition's in-order guarantee is not violated.

If you know more about your load pattern and want to explicitly have 1 unique task for each topic-partition, you can try to break up the config into separate configs, one for each topic and each having tasks.max of related number of partitions

---

> `offset.storage.partitions` related to max active connector task ?

-- No, they are not related.
You should have it set 25 (default) or more... it is better not touching it...

Comment: Thanks for your help, it gave me the motivation to digger the subject cause I was really thinking that it was related to offset.storage.partitions. I just added an answer showing that it's related to the number of partitions of the topics to consume.

Comment: If the answer was useful for you , you should at least +1 it...